# GA4 (Google Analytics) sessions based on UTM params

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am trying to fetch sessions from GA4 which are relevant to specific UTM params.

In GA3 we were able to use segments (`sessions::condition::ga:source==X;ga:medium==Y`) but I can not find a way to do this on GA4.

```
POST https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/#{property}:runReport`
```

Payload like this:

```
body = {
  "metrics": [
    {
      "name": "sessions::condition::ga:source==X;ga:medium==Y"
    }
  ], 
  "dimensions": [
    {
      "name": "date" 
    }
  ],
  "dateRanges": [
    {
      "startDate": '2022-01-01',
      "endDate": '2022-01-30',
      "name": "current_year"
    }
  ]
}
```

Returns: `Field sessions::condition::ga:source==X;ga:medium==Y is not a valid metric.`. Is there a way to do this via new API?

Should I use dimension filter to achieve that? I need to query on both source&medium but it is not clear how do I do this?

```
  "dimensionFilter": {
      "filter": {
        "fieldName": "firstUserMedium",
        "stringFilter": {
          "value": "Y"
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dimension filter on `sessionSource` & `sessionMedium` returns sessions that have those specific utm_source & utm_medium values. See the [dimensions & metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema) page for a description of these and other dimensions & metrics.

The needed dimension filter is similar to the following. See [Dimension Filters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/basics#dimension_filters) in Creating a Report for more info.

```
"dimensionFilter": {
  "andGroup": {
    "expressions": [
      {
        "filter": {
          "fieldName": "sessionSource",
          "stringFilter": {
            "value": "X"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "filter": {
          "fieldName": "sessionMedium",
          "stringFilter": {
            "value": "Y"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

Segments are not yet available today in the GA4 Data API.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check the [dimensions and metrcis](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema) list for GA4 they dont start with ga

```
POST https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/GA4_PROPERTY_ID:runReport
  {
    "dateRanges": [{ "startDate": "2020-09-01", "endDate": "2020-09-15" }],
    "dimensions": [{ "name": "country" }],
    "metrics": [{ "name": "activeUsers" }]
  }
```

Also at this time i don't think it supports segments.

Comment: GA 4 is not session based is only hit and user based